# How to convert wiki markup to RTF?

Tags: .net, markup, rtf

I'd like to create some formatted text in a .net RichTextBox control. It seems like a lot of hassle to use the existing mechanism for formatting, e.g. selection etc.

Some kind of markup would be much easier. I.e. just like markup works in this site. E.g.

```
Some **bold** text.
```

gives you "Some **bold** text".

Does anyone:

- know if anything like this exists,
- know of any C# code that can be modified to do this,
- or have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If read this article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/XHTML2RTF.aspx it should be quite easy to create your own Wiki2RTF converter class, or find a Wiki2Html and combine those two :-) !